# Is there a mySQL connector for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector, entity-model

The image below describes my problem.

[image]

There is no option for MySQL Server although i have installed the MySQL connector for Visual Studio 2012.
I want to use Entity model and i am stacked here.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MySQL for Visual Studio:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html

Because since version 6.7 MySql connector does not include anymore MySQL for Visual Studio integration

Comment: Nope. I have tried that before i posted my question and it did not working.

Comment: @anvlasop did you close visualstudio before installing? did you select the MySQL for Visual Studio component during installation?

Comment: Yes everything was done appropriately. I downloaded mysql installer and under Applications i selected ...for Visual Studio 2012. VS was closed indeed.

Comment: @anvlasop do you have  mysqlconnector referenced in the project?

Comment: What do you mean? I have added MySql.Data reference. Am i missing something else?

Comment: @anvlasop yes if the project has MySql.Data reference